# How to add a new record in the beginning of an existing dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, dictionary

I have defined the following fetch method as below to get the recording from the database. But I want to add another record to the beginning of an existing record just for frontend implementation. Please help me solve this issue.

```
<script>
  export default {
    components: {
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        versions: [],
      };
    },
    created: function() {
      this.fetchVersions();
    },
    methods: {     
      fetchVersions() {
        var that = this;
        var url = '/area/versions.json';

        this.$axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          that.versions = response.data;
        })
      },

    }
  };
</script>


Right now the versions array look like this: 

    versions: [
      {    
        name: 'Version 1',
        region: 'CBA 09',
      },
      {
        name: 'Version 2',
        region: 'CBA 11',
      }
    ]
```

I want to add the below to the beginning of versions

```
{
 name: Version 3
 region: CBA 21
}
```

So that versions look something like:

```
versions: [
       {
        name: Version 3
        region: CBA 21
      },
      {    
        name: 'Version 1',
        region: 'CBA 09',
      },
      {
        name: 'Version 2',
        region: 'CBA 11',
      }
    ]
```

Please help me figureout how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Array.unshift() method:

```
versions.unshift({
 name: 'Version 3'
 region: 'CBA 21'
});
```

[Array.prototype.unshift() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)